# How to come up with a probability score for each predicted value from a neural networks model?

Tags: machine-learning, python

I have some python code that creates and trains a neural networks model for predicting the column  'Cost'. It takes in a bunch of inputs and predicts the cost. Now, I'm trying to convert the predicted cost into a probability (more specifically, the probability of encountering this error (relative difference between expected and predicted cost) or larger). Here's what i did:

```
# Y_Actual is the actual cost (it is an array)
# predictions_array is an array of the predictions of cost that came from the neural networks model
error_list = ((abs(Y_Actual - predictions_array)) / Y_Actual) * 100
# I used the trimmed mean and trimmed sd to control for possible outliers
error_mean = trim_mean(error_list, 0.05)
trimmed_data = stats.trimboth(error_list, 0.05)
error_sd = np.std(trimmed_data)
prob_score_all = []
for i in error_list:
    z_score = (i - error_mean) / error_sd
    desiredProb = 1 - stats.norm.cdf(z_score) 
    prob_score_all.append(desiredProb)
```

This generally works well. That being said, if for example the actual cost is `$3` and the predicted cost is `$15`, this isn't a very significant difference. But the probability that gets assigned to it is so small because the code determines that the predicted cost is 5 times away from the actual cost. So, it ends up getting assigned a much smaller probability. On the other hand, if for example i had an actual cost of `$1,000,000` and predicted cost of `$700,000` it has a much larger probability compared to the previous example. Is there any way i can address this issue. I know this seems like a programming question but it's actually a statistical question on how to convert predicted values from machine learning models into probabilities.